# Accessing data from Google spreadsheet when data types are mixed

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a spreadsheet formatted as a table with a header and I want to read it into JS using the Google Visualization Query API.

```
var query=new google.visualization.Query(url);
query.send(handleGoogleResponse);
...

function handleGoogleResponse(response) {
    var data=response.getDataTable();
...
```

All works well when the fields are all *plain text* format, but if one of them is a *TimeStamp* format, the data gets wonky. Is there anyway to force the query to return unformatted data as strings? I've tried the format and option clauses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the Google handles the "shape" of the table differently when the header row is of a different type than the data in the columns below it.

This seems to work for both cases:

```
var query=new google.visualization.Query(url);
query.send(handleGoogleResponse);

function handleGoogleResponse(response) {
    var i,j,o,lab;
    var keys=[];
    var theData=[];
    var data=response.getDataTable();
    var cols=data.getNumberOfColumns(); 
    var rows=data.getNumberOfRows()
    var hasLabels=data.getColumnLabel(0) ? true : false;

    for (i=0;i<cols;++i) {
        if (hasLabels)  
            lab=$.trim(data.getColumnLabel(i)); 
        else    
            lab=$.trim(data.getFormattedValue(0,i));
        if (!lab)
            break;  
        keys.push(lab);
        var s=hasLabels ? 0 : 1;
        for (i=s;i<rows;++i) {
            o={};
            for (j=0;j<keys.length;++j) 
                o[keys[j]]=data.getValue(i,j);
            theData.push(o);    
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the Google spreadsheets site, in your sheet:

- Select your column
- Format -> Number -> Plain Text

now the data type for that column should be string.

Comment: yes. But I want to do that when I load the data via JS. My users don;t always do that...

Comment: the server you are requesting must reponse with the right format, see the reference here:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam

Comment: I appreciate the link, but that applies to hand-constructed tables, not importing ones from Google drive. I did find a way to solve the issue (see answer below)